# getSnapshotBeforeUpdate using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I implement the same logic that getSnapshotBeforeUpdate gives me using react hooks?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the [React Hooks FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#do-hooks-cover-all-use-cases-for-classes), there isn't a way to implement `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate` and `ComponentDidCatch` lifecycle method with hooks yet

> **Do Hooks cover all use cases for classes?**
>
> Our goal is for Hooks to cover all use cases for classes as soon as
>   possible. There are no Hook equivalents to the uncommon
>   `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate` and `componentDidCatch` lifecycles yet, but we
>   plan to add them soon.
>
> It is a very early time for Hooks, so some integrations like DevTools
>   support or Flow/TypeScript typings may not be ready yet. Some
>   third-party libraries might also not be compatible with Hooks at the
>   moment.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot get the snapshot data in any of the hooks (useLayoutEffect or useEffect) as both will give the updated DOM values by the time they are triggered, the best place to capture the data is just before the setting the state. for example here I am capturing the scroll position before setting the state.

```
function ChatBox(props){

  const [state, setState] = useState({chatFetched:[],isFetching:false});

  const listRef = useRef();
  const previousScrollDiff = useRef(0);
  
  // on mount 
  useEffect(()=>{
    getSomeMessagesApi().then(resp=>{
      const chatFetched = [...state.chatFetched,...resp];
      setState({chatFetched});
    })
  },[]);

  useLayoutEffect(()=>{
   // use the captured snapshot here
   listRef.current.scrollTop = listRef.current.scrollHeight - previousScrollDiff.current;

  },[state.chatFetched])
  
  useEffect(()=>{

    // don't use captured snapshot here ,will cause jerk effect in scroll

  },[state.chatFetched]);


  const onScroll = (event) => {
    const topReached = (event.target.scrollTop === 0);

    if(topReached && !state.isFetching){

      setState({...state, isFetching:true});

      getSomeMessagesApi().then(resp=>{
        const chatFetched = [...resp,...state.chatFetched];

        // here I am capturing the data ie.., scroll position

        previousScrollDiff.current = listRef.current.scrollHeight -listRef.current.scrollTop;
        setState({chatFetched, isFetching:false});
      })
    }
  }

  return (  
    <div className="ui container">
      <div 
        className="ui container chat list" 
        style={{height:'420px', width:'500px',overflow:'auto'}}
        ref={listRef}
        onScroll={onScroll}
        >
          {state.chatFetched.map((message)=>{
           return <ChatLi data ={message} key ={message.key}></ChatLi>
          })}
      </div>  
    </div>
   ); 
};
```

we can also useMemo to capture the data before dom update happens,

```
function ChatBox(props){

  const [state, setState] = useState({chatFetched:[],isFetching:false});

  const listRef = useRef();
  const previousScrollDiff = useRef(0);
  
  // on mount 
  useEffect(()=>{
    getSomeMessagesApi().then(resp=>{
      const chatFetched = [...state.chatFetched,...resp];
      setState({chatFetched});
    })
  },[]);

  useLayoutEffect(()=>{
   // use the captured snapshot here
   listRef.current.scrollTop = listRef.current.scrollHeight - previousScrollDiff.current;

  },[state.chatFetched])
  
  useEffect(()=>{

    // don't use captured snapshot here ,will cause jerk effect in scroll

  },[state.chatFetched]);

  useMemo(() => {
   // caputure dom info in use effect
    if(scrollUl.current){
       previousScrollDiff.current = scrollUl.current.scrollHeight - scrollUl.current.scrollTop;
    }
    
  }, [state.chatFetched]);

  const onScroll = (event) => {
    const topReached = (event.target.scrollTop === 0);

    if(topReached && !state.isFetching){

      setState({...state, isFetching:true});

      getSomeMessagesApi().then(resp=>{
        const chatFetched = [...resp,...state.chatFetched];
        setState({chatFetched, isFetching:false});
      })
    }
  }

  return (  
    <div className="ui container">
      <div 
        className="ui container chat list" 
        style={{height:'420px', width:'500px',overflow:'auto'}}
        ref={listRef}
        onScroll={onScroll}
        >
          {state.chatFetched.map((message)=>{
           return <ChatLi data ={message} key ={message.key}></ChatLi>
          })}
      </div>  
    </div>
   ); 
};
```

In the above examples I am trying to do the same that is shown here in the [getSnapshotBeforeUpdate react doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#getsnapshotbeforeupdate)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useMemo()` instead of `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate()`. Read more here about [how to memoize calculations with React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-memoize-calculations).

**Here a simple example:**

It always that the user types (onChange) an irrelevant state in point of view of the List Component is changed and because of this it re-rendering and can re-rendering more than 50 times it depends on the user typing, so it's used `useMemo()` to memoize the List Component and it stated that just `todoList` listens.

```js
import List from './List'

const todo = (props) => {
  const [inputIsValid, setInputIsValid] = useState(false)

  const inputValidationHandler = (event) => {
    if(event.target.value.trim() === '') {
      setInputIsValid(false)
    } else {
      setInputIsValid(true)
    }
  }

  return <React.Fragment>
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Todo"
      onChange={inputValidationHandler}
    />
    {
      useMemo(() => (
        <List items={todoList} onClick={todoRemoveHandler} />
      ), [todoList])
    }
  </React.Fragment>

}

export default todo
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: There isn't a react hook for it! But we can create a custom one!

That's using `useEffect()` and `useLayoutEffect()`! As they are the key elements!

The final example is all last! So make sure to check it (**Our custom hooks equivalent**).

### useEffect() and useLayoutEffect()

**useEffect** => useEffect runs asynchronously and after a render is painted to the screen.

1. You cause a render somehow (change state, or the parent re-renders)
2. React renders your component (calls it)
3. The screen is visually updated
4. THEN useEffect runs

> useEffect() => render() => dom mutation => repaint => useEffect() [access dom new state] (changing dom directly) => repaint

==> Meaning useEffect() is like `comonentDidUpdate()`!

**useLayoutEffect** => useLayoutEffect, on the other hand, runs synchronously after a render but before the screen is updated. That goes:

1. You cause a render somehow (change state, or the parent re-renders)
2. React renders your component (calls it)
3. useLayoutEffect runs, and React waits for it to finish.
4. The screen is visually updated

> useLayoutEffect() => render => dom mutation [detached] => useLayoutEffec() [access dom new state] (mutate dom) => repaint (commit, attach)

===> Meaning `useLayoutEffect()` run like `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate()`

Knowing this! We can create our custom hooks that allow us to do things like with `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate()` and `didComponentUpdate()`.

Such an example would be updating the scrolling for auto update in chat applications!

### usePreviousPropsAndState()

Similar to the `usePrevious()` hook mentionned in "[how to get previous prop and state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state)"

Here an hook implementation for saving and getting previous props and state!

```js
const usePrevPropsAndState = (props, state) => {
  const prevPropsAndStateRef = useRef({ props: null, state: null })
  const prevProps = prevPropsAndStateRef.current.props
  const prevState = prevPropsAndStateRef.current.state

  useEffect(() => {
    prevPropsAndStateRef.current = { props, state }
  })

  return { prevProps, prevState }
}
```

We can see how we need to pass the props and state object!

What you pass is what you get! So it's easy to work with! An object will do well!

#### useGetSnapshotBeforeUpdate & useComponentDidUpdate

Here the total solution or implementation

```js
const useGetSnapshotBeforeUpdate = (cb, props, state) => {
  // get prev props and state
  const { prevProps, prevState } = usePrevPropsAndState(props, state)

  const snapshot = useRef(null)


// getSnapshotBeforeUpdate (execute before the changes are comitted for painting! Before anythingg show on screen) - not run on mount + run on every update
  const componentJustMounted = useRef(true)
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (!componentJustMounted.current) { // skip first run at mount
           snapshot.current = cb(prevProps, prevState)  
    }
    componentJustMounted.current = false
  })


 // ________ a hook construction within a hook with closure __________
 const useComponentDidUpdate = cb => {
    // run after the changes are applied (commited) and apparent on screen
    useEffect(() => {
      if (!componentJustMounted.current) { // skip first run at mount
        cb(prevProps, prevState, snapshot.current)
      }
    })
  }
  // returning the ComponentDidUpdate hook!
  return useComponentDidUpdate
}
```

You can notice how we constructed the hook within the other hook! Make use of closure! And accessing elements directly! And linking the two hooks!

#### pre-commit phase and commit phase (and effects hooks)

I used those terms! What does it actually means ?

[image]

#### class example

From [the doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#getsnapshotbeforeupdate)

```
class ScrollingList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.listRef = React.createRef();
  }

  getSnapshotBeforeUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    // Are we adding new items to the list?
    // Capture the scroll position so we can adjust scroll later.
    if (prevProps.list.length < this.props.list.length) {
      const list = this.listRef.current;
      return list.scrollHeight - list.scrollTop;
    }
    return null;
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    // If we have a snapshot value, we've just added new items.
    // Adjust scroll so these new items don't push the old ones out of view.
    // (snapshot here is the value returned from getSnapshotBeforeUpdate)
    if (snapshot !== null) {
      const list = this.listRef.current;
      list.scrollTop = list.scrollHeight - snapshot;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.listRef}>{/* ...contents... */}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

#### Our custom hooks equivalent

```js
const App = props => {
  // other stuff ...

  const useComponentDidUpdate = useGetSnapshotBeforeUpdate(
    (prevProps, prevState) => {
      if (prevProps.list.length < props.list.length) {
        const list = listRef.current;
        return list.scrollHeight - list.scrollTop;
      }
      return null;
    },
    props,
    state
  )

  useComponentDidUpdate((prevProps, prevState, snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot !== null) {
      const list = listRef.current;
      list.scrollTop = list.scrollHeight - snapshot;
    }
  })

  // rest ...
}
```

useEffectLayout() in `useGetSnapshotBeforeUpdate` hook will execute first!

useEffect() in `useComponentDidUpdate` will execute after!

As just was shown in the lifecyle schema!