# React Page Scrolls on top after re render by useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, material-ui, react-hooks

My problem - whenever i use `<Tabs>` component the `onChange` method calls the `handleTabChange` function. The component gets called again and the after repainting the `useEffect` gets called. This causes my page to scroll on top.

How do i make sure the `handleChange` and `useEffect` does not cause the page to scroll on top?

```
export function VarianceGraph({ variancesGraphData }) {
  if (variancesGraphData === undefined) {
    return null;
  }
  const [currentProject, setCurrentProject] = useState('All');
  const [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = useState('ABCD');
  const projectCodes = prepareProjectCodesForConsumption(variancesGraphData);
  let data = {};

  function handleProjectChange(event) {
    const { value } = event.target;
    setCurrentProject(value);
  }

  function handleTabChange(event, tabValue) {
    setCurrentTab(tabValue);
  }

  data = prepareProjectDataForRechartsConsumption(currentProject, variancesGraphData);
  const hideABCD = data.ABCD.length < 1;
  const hideBCDF = data['BCDF'].length < 1;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hideABCD && hideBCDF) {
      setCurrentTab('None');
    } else if (hideABCD) {
      setCurrentTab('BCDF');
    } else if (hideBCDF) {
      setCurrentTab('ABCD');
    }
  });

  return (
    <Grid container direction="row" justify="flex-start" alignItems="flex-start">
      <Grid item xs={12}>
```

I have tried -

I need to have the `setCurrentTab` in some function so as to not render infinitely.

I have tried using the `useLayoutEffect` but it has the same behavior.

I can write the component code further if required. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding right, you only want your `useEffect` code run once after `VarianceGraph` render.

Try to add a second argument `[]` to your `useEffect`, otherwise the code in `useEffect` will run after any state change.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and searched the problem and found the below solutions

[Keep scroll-y after rerender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53044740/keep-scroll-y-after-rerender)

But the problem is the `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate` is not available in hooks
as can be seen here

[getSnapshotBeforeUpdate using react hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53537529/getsnapshotbeforeupdate-using-react-hooks)

So, the best option is to convert the component to a class component and follow the example here : https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#getsnapshotbeforeupdate

Sample code, in your case, you might have to bind the `document.body.scrollHeight`

```
class ScrollingList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.listRef = React.createRef();
  }

  getSnapshotBeforeUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    // Are we adding new items to the list?
    // Capture the scroll position so we can adjust scroll later.
    if (prevProps.list.length < this.props.list.length) {
      const list = this.listRef.current;
      return list.scrollHeight - list.scrollTop;
    }
    return null;
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    // If we have a snapshot value, we've just added new items.
    // Adjust scroll so these new items don't push the old ones out of view.
    // (snapshot here is the value returned from getSnapshotBeforeUpdate)
    if (snapshot !== null) {
      const list = this.listRef.current;
      list.scrollTop = list.scrollHeight - snapshot;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.listRef}>{/* ...contents... */}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I had done that before but it still caused me some issue. I am not able to recall. Let me go home and check this out

Comment: It still shows the same behavior with both the approaches. Since the data is used in the return component, it gives empty data.

Comment: Honestly I have to edit my question, it's not even because of useEffect. I removed useEffect and it still scrolls back on top.

Comment: May be a problem with the grid layout you are using.or when the component is empty in between renders and browser loses the scroll position

Comment: Is there an easy fix to scrollBack to Bottom in the useEffect function? It would temporarily solve my issue.

Comment: It is weird how, if chrome dev tools (inspect element) is open, the page does not scroll on Top.